# Showing matrices are unitary similar

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A , B \in M_2$. Show that they are unitary similar to each other if and only if $Tr(W(A,A^*)) = Tr(W(B,B^*))$ for the words $W(s,t) = s , s^2, st$.

So far what I have done is let $$ A=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}
B=
\begin{bmatrix}
x & y \\
z & w \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then since we have $Tr(A)=Tr(B)$, $Tr(A^2) = Tr(B^2)$  and $Tr(AA^*) = Tr(BB^*)$ we have respectively,

$$a+d = x+w$$
$$a^2 + 2bc + d^2 = x^2 + 2yz + w^2$$
$$aa^* + bb^* + cc^* + dd^* = xx^* + yy^* +zz^* + ww^*$$

So we do the following to the second equation:

$$(a+d)^2 - 2ad + 2bc = x^2 +2yz + w^2 $$
$$(x+w)^2 - 2ad + 2bc = x^2 + 2yz + w^2$$
$$x^2+2xw + w^2 -2ad + 2bc= x^2+2yz + w^2$$
$$2xw-2ad + 2bc = 2yz$$
$$ad-bc = xw - yz$$
Therefore $det(A) = det(B)$ moreover $p_A(t) = p_B(t)$ (the characteristic polynomials.) And so $\sigma(A) = \sigma(B)$. Now here is where I am unsure. I would like to be able to use Sylvesters Theorem to get that there is a nonzero matrix $X$ that solves equation

$$AX - XB =0 $$

Therefore I would just need to show that $X$ is unitary. So my question is does my logic hold up? Am I able to get a nonzero solution like I claim? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We give a proof using the Specht's theorem. cf.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specht%27s_theorem#cite_note-5

Remark. If we restrict ourselves to the case n = 2, there may exist some elementary direct proof.

$\textbf{Specht's theorem (1940).}$ Let $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$.

$A,B$ are unitarily similar IFF the  infinity of equalities

$tr(W(A,A^*))=tr(W(B,B^*))$ hold for all (finite) words $W$ in two letters.

$\textbf{Proposition.}$ When $n=2$ the Specht's condition can be reduced to

i) $tr(A)=tr(B)$, ii) $tr(A²)=tr(B^2)$, iii) $tr(AA^*)=tr(BB^*)$.

$\textbf{Proof}.$ $\Rightarrow$ is clear.

$\Leftarrow$ $\{i), ii)\}$ is equivalent to say that the characteristic polynomials $\chi_A,\chi_B$ are equal.

Using Cayley Hamilton, we obtain  $A^k=u_kA+v_kI_2$ and, therefore $B^k=u_kB+v_kI_2,{A^*}^k=\overline {u_k}A^*+\overline{v_k}I_2,{B^*}^k=\overline {u_k}B^*+\overline{v_k}I_2$.

A word in $A,A^*$ (there is an infinity of such words) has the form $W(A,A^*)=A^p{A^*}^qA^r{A^*}^s\cdots$; according to the above equalities, $W(A,A^*)$ is a linear combination of terms of the form $I_2,AA^*AA^*\cdots,A^*AA^*\cdots$ and $W(B,B^*)$ is the SAME combination of terms of the form $I_2,BB^*BB^*\cdots,B^*BB^*\cdots$.

$\{\det(AA^*)=\det(BB^*),iii)\}$ is equivalent to say that the characteristic polynomials $\chi_{AA^*},\chi_{BB^*}$ are equal (same result for $\chi_{A^*A},\chi_{B^*B}$).

Finally, $W(A,A^*)$ is a linear combination of these $7$ terms  $AA^*,A^*A,AA^*A,A^*AA^*,A,A^*,I_2$ and $W(B,B^*)$ is the SAME combination of these $7$ terms $BB^*,B^*B,BB^*B,B^*BB^*,B,B^*,I_2$.

It remains to show that $tr(AA^*A)=tr(BB^*B),tr(A^*AA^*)=tr(B^*BB^*)$, that is easy.  $\square$